# HackerRank challenge write a function: Test case 1 failed

Tags: python-3.x, loops, code-testing

this is my code for the hackerRank challenge [write a function](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/write-a-function/problem)

```
def is_leap(year):
    x=str(year)
    y=int(x[-2:])

    return y%4==0 or y%400==0 and y%100!=0


year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

All 5 test cases worked except for one, when year=2100, and I'd like to know why? what's wrong with my code? 
edit: 
after running the code I got the following:

Compiler Message:
Wrong Answer

Input (stdin):
2100

Expected Output:
False

Comment: please post the problem statement in the question as well as the expected input and output, and what you're getting

Comment: @pushkin i've put a link to the problem statement (click on "write a function" in my question above).

Comment: @pushkin I've edited now and included the expected input and output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you only test on the last two digits, as seen by `y=int(x[-2:])`, which there's really no reason to. The program constraints already tell you the input will be an int from 1900-10000, so you can just work with year. Also, your return statement will evaluate the `or` before the `and` (See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)), so the last thing it checks will be `!=100`, thus breaking it for the `400` case.

Comment: Right explanation. As a remark, one correct possibility of writing the logical expression could be:
`(y% 4 == 0 and y % 100 != 0) or y % 400 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why your code doesn't work, but I have the solution:

```
def is_leap(year):
    if year%4 == 0:
        if year%100 == 0:
            if year%400 == 0:
                return True #divisible by 4, divisible by 100, and divisible by 400
            else:
                return False #divisible by 4 and divisible by 100
        else:
            return True #divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100
    else:
        return False #not divisible by 4
```

And to test it:

```
for i in range(1000, 2501, 4):
    if not is_leap(i):
        print(str(i)) # this will print all the "irregular" leap years between 1000 and 2500
```

Also, I'm not sure where you are running that code, but the question does ask for *boolean* values (True or False) and you are returning the years instead, so that might be why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the output of the first code but would you please explain the second one?

Comment: What do you mean by the *second one*?

Comment: are you talking about the `for i in range` loop?

Comment: That was just to test the function.  That loop will print all the "irregular" leap years between 1000 and 2500

Comment: now I get it. btw, tried your code and it worked. thanks a lot.

Comment: Your welcome!  If this helped you should accept it as your answer :)

Comment: It was so helpful and it corrected many mistaken concepts i had but I still owe it to you xD

Answer (score 0):

I like your concise code of evaluating and returning result in one line of code!
However, two issues with your code:
1) You are looking at the last two digits instead of testing the whole number
2) The logical evaluation order is incorrect.
Try this simple code

```
def is_leap(year):
    y=int(year)
    return  y%400==0 or (y%100 != 0 and y%4==0)
year = input()
print(is_leap(year))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it. Indeed, checking the last two digits was wrong along with the logical evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    # Write your logic here
    if year % 400 == 0:
        leap = True
    elif year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
        leap = True
    return leap
```